# Зависает установка на 73% Magento 2

Tags: php, windows, cms, magento

Возникла проблема при установке Magento 2.2.5. При каждой попытке установки после перезапуска сервера доходит до определенного процента и зависает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал редактировать php.ini(memory_limit = 2536M и max_execution_time = 3600000). Не помогло.
При каждой попытке создать новую базу и пройти весь путь сначала, каждый раз доходит до разной отметки. Вот что выдает консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Краткое содержание лога(последние логи):

```
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':
Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':

Module 'Magento_Analytics':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Klarna_Core':
Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_Reports':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Amazon_Login':

Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':

Module 'Magento_Review':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Robots':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Amazon_Payment':
Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CustomerSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ThemeSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ProductLinksSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ReviewSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Signifyd':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_SalesRuleSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_TaxSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':

Module 'Magento_CmsSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_SalesSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Usps':
Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Klarna_Kp':
Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProductSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_WidgetSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_WishlistSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Shopial_Facebook':

Module 'Temando_Shipping':
Upgrading data... 

Module 'Vertex_Tax':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Data post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Theme':
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Снеси установки сервера и бд .
Поставь заново , проверь права пользователя мадженты к базе данных , пароль и права.
Создай ещё 1 пользователя , дай ему все права .
Пошарь в настройках виртуального сервера .

https://numediaweb.com/configure-virtual-hosts/950

Должно все получится :)